# Fiddler: Is it possible to replace/hide part of URL without affecting the content?

Tags: proxy, debug, fiddler, man-in-the-middle

I'm using Fiddler debugging proxy, And the code below can intercept the server(YouTube) data and modify the HTML information before  it reaches the client(my web broswer).

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.youtube.com") && oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type","text/html")){

            oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
            oSession.utilReplaceInResponse("old string","new string");
        }
```

Now, I want to replace/hide the word `dolphin` from http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=`dolphin`&page=3. How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (oSession.url.Contains("search_query=dolphin")) {
   oSession.url = oSession.url.Replace("search_query=dolphin","search_query=");
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some explanation, instead of just posting a command line ?